# Create backup from /etc/apt/source.list

Tags: 20.04, package-management, dependencies, backup

I have been trying to build the Software Carla and to do that I have to give the following command

`sudo apt-get install build-essential clang-8 lld-8 g++-7 cmake ninja-build libvulkan1 python python-pip python-dev python3-dev python3-pip libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev tzdata sed curl unzip autoconf libtool rsync libxml2-dev git`

After doing it I get an error message that says the following

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:9.2) but 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I found an answer on how to solve this but first I have to create a backup of /etc/apt/source.list, which I don't know how to do. Can anyone explain how to do this?

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `/etc/apt/sources.list` is just a file, you could create a "backup" by copying the file to something with a different name:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.orig
```

This will create a new file in `/etc/apt` called `sources.orig` with the very same contents as `sources.list`. `sudo` is needed because the file is owned by the `root` account.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wanted to be sure :)